# Sorting out a list correctly ?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have to code a script which find the biggest integer of a list.

```
tour = int(input('Combien de valeurs voulez-vous entrer ? '))
tableau = []
for i in range(tour):
    valeur = input('Entrez des valeurs :')
    tableau.append(valeur)
tableau.sort()
print('La valeur maximale entrée est :',tableau[len(tableau)-1])
```

And I have that (idle) :

```
Combien de valeurs voulez-vous entrer ? 10
Entrez des valeurs :200
Entrez des valeurs :1
Entrez des valeurs :5
Entrez des valeurs :9
Entrez des valeurs :41
Entrez des valeurs :52
Entrez des valeurs :69
Entrez des valeurs :58
Entrez des valeurs :32
Entrez des valeurs :01
La valeur maximale entrée est : 9
>>> tableau
['01', '1', '200', '32', '41', '5', '52', '58', '69', '9']
```

Why the list is not correctly sorted out ?

Comment: You should be using a selection algorithm not sorting algorithm.E.g. use Quickselect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert each entry to an integer, currently it is sorting them as strings:

```
tableau.append(int(valeur))
```

Comment: upvoted. But you could elaborate and provide an alternative, in case the OP wanted to keep the list elements as strings. e.g. `tableau.sort(key=int)`